# Runtime Generic Constraint Error with Moq and NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I'm using NUnit and Moq to test a class which uses a generic WCF service client wrapper [I wrote](http://geekswithblogs.net/mrsteve/archive/2011/06/30/generic-disposable-wcf-service-client.aspx), and I've run into an error I can't figure out. I have the following interface:

```
public interface IService
{
    void Call();
}
```

...implemented by the following service client:

```
public class ServiceClient : ClientBase<IService>, IService
{
    public void Call()
    {
    }
}
```

...and wrapped by this class with the following generic constraints:

```
public class ServiceClientWrapper<TClient, TService>
    where TClient : ClientBase<TService>, TService
    where TService : class
{
    public virtual TService CreateServiceClient()
    {
        return (TService)Activator.CreateInstance<TClient>();
    }
}
```

To make it testable I have a wrapper factory which I can mock. The wrapper factory interface is this:

```
public interface IServiceClientWrapperFactory
{
    ServiceClientWrapper<TClient, TService>
        CreateServiceClientWrapper<TClient, TService>()
        where TClient : ClientBase<TService>, TService
        where TService : class;
}
```

I test this set up using this code:

```
// A mock IService to return from my mock service wrapper:
var mockService = new Mock<IService>();

// A mock client wrapper to return from my mock wrapper factory:
var mockClientWrapper = 
    new Mock<ServiceClientWrapper<ServiceClient, IService>>();
mockClientWrapper
    .Setup(mcw => mcw.CreateServiceClient())
    .Returns(mockService.Object);

// A mock wrapper factory to inject into a client object:
var mockClientWrapperFactory = new Mock<IServiceClientWrapperFactory>();
mockClientWrapperFactory
    .Setup(mcwf => mcwf.CreateServiceClientWrapper<ServiceClient, IService>())
    .Returns(mockClientWrapper.Object);

// Get the mock client wrapper from the mock wrapper factory - boom!
mockClientWrapperFactory.Object
    .CreateServiceClientWrapper<ServiceClient, IService>();
```

The error is:

> GenericArguments[0], 'TService', on
>   'ServiceClientWrapper`2[TClient,TService]'
>   violates the constraint of type
>   parameter 'TClient'.

The constraints are the same wherever I've stated them, it compiles and runs just fine, the error isn't thrown if I implement `IServiceClientWrapperFactory` and run it without Moq... any ideas?

Comment: Instead of `return (TService)Activator.CreateInstance<TClient>();`, couldn't you just add the `new()` constraint, and new it up directly?  Also, it seems like you're making a simple problem much harder than it needs to be.  I don't see the rest of your code, but it seems like you could simply inject `IService` into the classes that use them, and throw away all this code.

Comment: I could if the class I really use for that had a parameterless constructor, but [it doesn't](http://geekswithblogs.net/mrsteve/archive/2011/06/30/generic-disposable-wcf-service-client.aspx). For the purposes of the question you can ignore that line. Good point re: injecting an IService directly, but in the real application the class is creating WCF service clients, which would mean the class' clients would have to create WCF service clients... the clients could use the factory, but it's kinda incidental to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played with the code a bit, and I get the same result.  As far as I can tell, there isn't anything wrong with your definitions.

It seems that it might be a bug in [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/), when implementing mocks that have various combinations of generic constraints on them.

I tried removing various constraints (and commenting out or modifying code, as required).  It seems if I remove `TService` from `where TClient : ... , TService`, then I don't get this error.

This seems further corroborated by the fact that there have been multiple similar bugs in the past:

- http://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=127
- http://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=177

FYI, the version I used to repro your problem was: Moq.4.0.10827, NET40 (not NET40-RequiresCastle)

Comment: Yeah, I've found if I change `where TClient : ClientBase<TService>, TService` to `where TClient : ClientBase<TService>` it works ok - just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything obvious. Thanks for checking that out :)